# CMD: Wild card for all folder and sub folder

Tags: cmd, window, wildcard

I am trying to use a cmd command for all folder and its subfolder.

```
cacls "F:\Testing\*" /e /c /d %username%
```

all the folders and files in Testing are affected but the sub folders of those affected folder

```
F:\Testing\Folder\a
F:\Testing\Folder\b
etc..
```

are not affected by the command.

I also try

```
cacls "F:\Testing\*\*" /e /c /d %username%
```

but it does not work either.
Is there any wildcard that work for all sub-sub-... folders?

Answer (score 1):

I've never used the CACLS command, but the built in help (`cacls /?`) indicates you want the `/T` option.

```
/T            Changes ACLs of specified files in
              the current directory and all subdirectories.
```

Whenever you have a question on how to use a Windows console command, you should always first check the built in help. Nearly all commands support the `/?` option to display help.